# Keep notes associated with applicants?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Right now I have a very simple .txt file I'm using to keep track of applicants. I really wish I could just put all the applicant stuff into one spot. I'd like a very simple system that lets me add weighted pros/cons to applicants as I go through interviews and screening stages with them.

For example, I have a simple system:

I have three lists: rejected, screened, pending review.

Screened applicants enter the interview stage where I create a weighted pro/con list such as...

```
John Doe
3+Sounds like he knows what he's talking about
2-Never seen a single line of code from this guy...
1-Lazy/Unprofessional?

John Smith
4+Actually solved problem
3-Sloppy code {
               -Define() use.
               -Mixed tabs and spaces
               -Define used as global constant
               -OOP example was weird.
               -Both have wrong answer
               -Both are just really using loops
             }

etc...
```

Having a single place to keep notes alone as raw text would be great, having a feature that lets me aggregate and helps me evaluate them would be nicer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notes can now be stored with candidates using the candidate manager.  Once you save a candidates from search, you can now save any notes you'd like to their candidate card.  You can also create a summary of each candidate for a quick reference in the candidate manager list view.

Comment: +1  I don't suppose [my request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127130/careers-change-order-of-sections-in-pdf-export) is anywhere on your development queue?  FWIW I'd be more than willing to pay good money for a "pro" careers account that had features like this.

Comment: @AdamRackis I honestly can't say much more than it's not on the schedule this week.  The feature I am currently working on is job seeker focused but not related to developer profiles.