# Careers: change order of sections in PDF export

Tags: feature-request, support, jobs

Currently on one's Career's profile you can organize, re-order and hide pretty much everything—except for the sections themselves.  It would be great if we could actually move entire sections up and down, rather than just the items within each section.

The main benefit would be that the PDF export would (presumably) reflect this new order.  Currently when you make a PDF export of your resume, the education section is always below experience; it would be nice to move that up.

[image]

Comment: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25040/ability-to-change-order-of-education-experience), you can change the order on the site. Shouldn't the formatting of the exported PDF just coincide with your preferences on the site? You have to remember to consider all of us who have far more *education* than we do experience. :-)

Comment: @TheEstablishment That link talks about ordering the items within a section, this question is about ordering the sections.

Comment: Man, now I *really* want to know what your thesis topic was. I didn't care before...

Comment: @The - it was 2006, and the only (more or less) ORM for .NET was NHibernate.  I hated it.  My thesis was that I wrote a simple ORM that scanned your DB and auto-genned data access classes based on the data mapper pattern (and let you customize relationships if no FKs were present).  The entities weren't persistent ignorant, but they were easy to use for the non-giant enterprise applications.  And then linq came out and made it obsolete.  Somewhat sad, but like Gould said: "obsolescence is fate devoutly to be wished, lest science wither and die."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is not any way to organize the sections on the pdf.

Comment: I'm the careers.SO's biggest fan, but please seriously consider adding this feature.  With how amazing everything else is, I can't imagine it would be too tough.  I just hate having my Master's in Comp Sci beneath my Air Force job from 2004 :-)

Comment: @AdamRackis It's truly awesome hearing from fans!  We would be happy to make the change, but it's like all other features and goes on the usefulness stack.  The more people who vote for your request, the higher up the stack it will go and the faster it will get changed.  It might be better to request reorganizing the sections on your profile and having this be an side effect feature.

Comment: Done - with freehand and everything!

Comment: @Nick 18 upvotes and 2.5 years later, what's the status of the request regarding the usefulness stack? :)

Comment: @Nick 24 upvotes and 3.5 years later, what's the status of the request regarding the usefulness stack? :)

Comment: Indeed, @Nick, is there any idea whether this'll be slated for development?

Comment: I've dropped a link in the Careers chat, but I am no longer on that team, so it's out of my hands.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a nice update.

I too would love to reorganize the sections of the Stack Careers page. Of course, if this had already been applied to items, this should be easily reapplied to the sections of the page. Now some people would like to see the page without any sorting or with their type of sorting, so I would recommend that the viewer get to see the sections ordered the way their own sections are ordered. If the viewer doesn't have Stack Careers (is viewing still possible?), the sections will be in default order.

Of course to organize these sections, you could use some buttons to move the sections up and down or apply these in the Settings place and let the user move each section there. And thank you for serving our United States Air Force (attempts salute...).

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a giant piece of low-hanging fruit - really not sure why nobody's picked it yet.  And thank you for the kind words :)